# No post found matching the query

Tags: django, django-views

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')
```

When I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/post/1`, it says no post found matching the query

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJPsI.jpg)

Comment: can you try 127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/ (with the slash at the end)

Comment: And does a `Post` object exist with an ID of 1?

Comment: I have tried it with the slash, three objects exist in Post

Comment: *three objects exist in Post*. That doesn't mean that there is a post with id=1. If the post with id=1 is deleted, the database does not fill in the gap when you create a new post. The ids could be (say) 3, 7, and 10. You could check the ids in the Django admin by looking at the URL (e.g. `/admin/yourapp/post/<id here>/`), or open the Django shell and run `from yourapp.models import post; print([post.pk for post in Post.objects.all()])`.

Comment: This is very useful man, Thank you so much, i have also facing the same problem becoz i have deleted the first 3 post and try to get the post with id 1 , so its obvious to get error

i have run the query on django shell

`from blog.models import Post`
`print([post.pk for post in Post.objects.all()])`

and the output is 

`[5, 6, 7]`

and when i try to navigate with `post/5/`

its working 


thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

## In Views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
   lookup_field = 'id'

   def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
      kwargs = self.kwargs
      kw_id = kwargs.get('id')
      return Post.objects.get(id=kw_id)
```

Comment: # In urls.py
path('post/<int:id>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),

Comment: It is showing Post matching query does not exist. DOES NOT EXIST AT /post/2